# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'feat'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tree, data-science, decision-tree

I'm having quite a weird issue with my code:

So I am trying to build a classifier and in my 'predict' part of the code I have written:

```
def predict(self, feature):
        node = self.tree
        for i in range(len(feature)):
            if feature[node.feat] == 0:
                 node = node.left
            else:
                 node = node.right
```

To check whether to move left or right.

And this is my node class:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.feat = 0
```

However, when I run the code, I seem to be getting the issue
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'feat'

Comment: Just to add, when I do 'print(node.feat)' or 'print(node.feat == 0)' everything runs fine, it just somehow doesn't work in the if statement

Comment: Add all relevant information to the question itself and show us enough code to see where `node` originates from.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad the issue is solved,

I was just returning an int in one of my recursive call instead of a node object